# Anomalous diffusion in a system of confined interacting particles

Tags: interactions, diffusion, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have a system of charged particles confined parabolically. I want to analytically study anomalous diffusion in such a system using Langevin Dynamics. In a system of non-interacting particles there exists some model for anomalous diffusion like fractional langevin motion. But I don't have any idea how to incorporate interparticle interaction into the model. The system of particles I am considering interact among themselves via pairwise additive Coulomb potential. Can anyone give some idea ?